# Can not make blueimp-image-gallery work with jade in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I've been trying to make [blueimp-image-gallery](https://www.npmjs.org/package/blueimp-image-gallery) work with Jade on my Node.js server.
I've followed the instructions and came up with this .jade page:

```
extends layout

block content

  h1 Test

  div(id='blueimp-gallery-dialog', data-show='fade', data-hide='fade')
    div(class='blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-carousel blueimp-gallery-controls')
      div(class='slides')
      a(class='prev') ‹
      a(class='next') ›
      a(class='play-pause')

  div(id='links')
    a(href='http://mypage.com/1.jpg' title='Frente' data-dialog)
      img(src='http://mypage.com/2.jpg' alt='Frente')
    a(href='http://mypage.com/6.jpg' title='Piscina' data-dialog)
      img(src='http://mypage.com/6.jpg' alt='Piscina')
    a(href='http://mypage.com/0.jpg' title='Garagem' data-dialog)
      img(src='http://mypage.com/0.jpg' alt='Garagem')


  script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js')
  script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js')
  script(src='http://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js')
  script(src='js/blueimp-gallery.min.js')
```

For some reason all I see are static links to the pictures referenced above. When I click them, instead of see the galery as the [example](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-Image-Gallery/) show I get redirected to the image link itself.
Blueimp-image-gallery pages states a few requirements, but I'm not sure if I need them or how to install them.
Can you help me to make it work?

Comment: Does your JS console show any errors?

Comment: @TimothyStrimple that was a great advice. The script was renamed from `js/blueimp-gallery.min.js` to `js/jquery.image-gallery.min.js`. Post it as an answer and I will give you the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your javascript console to see if there are any javascript errors on the page. If there are, they should give you a place to start when looking for a fix!

Comment: Indeed there was an error. The script was renamed from js/blueimp-gallery.min.js to js/jquery.image-gallery.min.js therefore a 404 (not found) message was thrown. Thanks!